# Asp Core UsePathBase : how to deal with AJAX calls?

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware

I want to host two version of my ASP Core website on the same VPS, one for each supplied environement (Staging and Test). I would like both web sites to be accessible from a subfolder of the same URL:

- http://www.mywebsite/Staging
- http://www.mywebsite/Test

After reading a lot I found the following Github issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/815

This tip works **but** for AJAX calls it crashes: Indeed, the JavaScript calls are not aware of this new path (BUG?). All requests are sent to the root base path (ignoring `/Staging` or `/Test`).

I partially solved it usig a middleware that redirects my AJAX calls to the correct path. It works for GET requests but it obviously fails for POST request that have a body.

Note that if we don't redirect, and just change the original PathBase request in the middleware, if the API call needs any authentication schema, it will throws a 401 error: The original PathBase is the root `/` where the response has a different path base, i.e. `/Staging`, then the cookie in the header prevents from this cross path base request/response.

**Could someone tell me what is the recomanded practice to achieve my needs?**

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env
{
    app.UsePathBase($"/{env.EnvironmentName}");
    ...
}
```

My Middleware :

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Headers[RequestedWithHeader] == XmlHttpRequest)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.PathBase))
        {
            if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post.Method)
            {

                // Do what ?
            }
            else
            {
                //Get request : set environement name + original path + original query string
                context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.Path.ToString().Insert(0, "/" + _env.EnvironmentName) + context.Request.QueryString);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, your client-side code will not be able to automatically change its code based on the path base that is active for the current request. JavaScript code is (usually) static content, so unless you actually rewrite the code dynamically, it *cannot* update URLs that are embedded inside.

You could determine the base path from the current request’s URL but that is a rather fragile solution since you need to find a logic that will work regardless of where in the application you are. So doing so is not recommended.

The overall problem is that on the client-side, there is no concept of a path base (or even an environment). So you will have to transfer that knowledge from the server to the client. And just like the path base is set for the server-side code using the path base middleware, you will need some server-side code that will pass the path base to the client-side code.

What I personally do is just configure the root path to the API in the application layout. So my `_Layout.cshtml` contains the following line:

```
<body data-api="@Url.Content("~/api/")">
```

That way, I can then retrieve the root path to the API using `document.body.dataset.api` in JavaScript. My AJAX calls are then all made so they respect that value. That way, I can host the site at any path, and the AJAX calls will use the proper path too.

You could also just use `"~"` as the content path to just refer to the root of your application. And you could also expose this value in a JavaScript variable inside a `<script>` block instead, if you prefer that.

Comment: Well, before I got your answer I move to a full 'front solution' as you recommanded. But I extracted the ENV name from the URL (window.location.pathname) and I set a global javascript variable that I concatenated to all my url AJAX calls. It's not pretty as I had to move forward to all my calls but it works. Thanks

Comment: That’s what I was referring with fragile solution. You can certainly try to parse the current URL on the client, but that’s bound to be more complicated and might cause problems in edge cases. In addition, you are effectively duplicating the path base logic. That’s why I’d suggest to just pass the root path to the client.